# CSS issue: How to cut the center part of a button in a circle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to shape a button in to a circle. Following the code from here: https://www.bootply.com/Tou8fnpxJW#

I am using Bootstrap v4

It was pretty successful. But one issue remain, it looks like this:
[image]
It cut the button with the top-left part. So it doesn't align with the text below.

```css
.wizard-step p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.wizard-step button[disabled] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.wizard-row:before {
  top: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.wizard-step {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-justified">
  <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
    <a id="tab_start" type="button" class="nav-link active btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step1" title="Step 1">1</a>
    <p>Start report</p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="tab_report" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step2" title="Step 2">2</a>
    <p>Report payroll</p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="tab_review" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step3" title="Step 3">3</a>
    <p>Review and submit</p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="tab_confirm" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step4" title="Step 4">4</a>
    <p>Print confirmation</p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="tab_pay" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-5" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step5" title="Step 5">5</a>
    <p>View balance or pay</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This chunk of code seems pretty straightforward. Let me know if it is not clear. I'll use the code snippet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: simply add this `.nav-link{margin:auto}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Temani Afif said in the comments, adding `.nav-link{margin:auto}` works for me.

Comment: it should be comment, now you can comment other's question also.